# NTFS mount using fstab is forced to nosuid,nodev

Tags: mount, fstab, ntfs, fuse

I'm having problems with automatically mounting my HDD using fstab entry.

In my `fstab` I added the following entry:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/CE20D46C20D45D51 /mnt/data1 auto default,exec,dev,suid 0 0
```

Whenever I try to remount it I get (from reading `/proc/mounts`):

```
/dev/sda1 /mnt/data1 fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
```

The problem is that I need to have dev and exec enabled, but this is not working whatever options I add or remove from my `fstab` entry. Any ideas?

EDIT:

**Linux:** Linux Mint Mate 17.2 Rafaela

**Kernel version:** Linux version 3.16.0-38-generic

**File System:** fuseblk (ntfs)

dmesg doesn't show any messages after performing following commands:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda1
sudo mount -a
```

in `/var/log/syslog` I can find:

```
    Unmounting /dev/sda1 (Data1)
    Version 2013.1.13AR.1 external FUSE 29
    Mounted /dev/sda1 (Read-Write, label "Data1", NTFS 3.1)
    Cmdline options: rw
    Mount options: rw,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,fsname=/dev/sda1,blkdev,blksize=4096
    Ownership and permissions disabled, configuration type 7
```

EDIT2:

My full fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sdb8 during installation
UUID=fd6f2b28-add9-43d2-90e4-e8c619b881e1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /HOME was on /dev/sdb9 during installation
UUID=b85b696e-7306-4489-8370-c1b14562ab65 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sdb1 during installation
UUID=0670-E6CA  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sdb10 during installation
UUID=dc53c42f-e148-4eb5-9e68-c70cbb2c03cd none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/CE20D46C20D45D51 /mnt/data1 auto users,exec,dev,suid 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2A6AD5C96AD59245 /mnt/data2 auto suid,exec,dev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

EDIT3:

Remounting it using:

```
mount -o remount,exec,dev /mnt/data1
```

Seems to work, but why doesn`t this work using fstab? I want this to happen automatically.

Comment: is there a virtualization or container or selinux ? after the mount,  can you cut and post  the last lines of dmesg and /var/log/messages ?

Comment: please post also kernel, linux  and ntfs-3g versions

Comment: Posted some extra information I could find.

Comment: have you to fstab entries for the same disk or mount point ?

Comment: Don't think so, added my full fstab file to the post to be sure.

Comment: have you tried mounting it manually.

Comment: Remounting using: mount -o remount,exec,dev /mnt/data1 seems to work, but it why can't I auto mount it this way?

Comment: Please test if this syntax works any better: `UUID=CE20D46C20D45D51 /mnt/data1 auto default,exec,dev,suid 0 0`

Comment: This is similar to a permissions option not being honored problem that I just solved: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310470/what-is-overriding-the-fstab-permissions-mounting-option/310528#310528  It might help you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this (mounting NTFS with suid and dev options from fstab) may not possible without modifying NTFS-3G or mount(8).

The problem is, the mount(8) program doesn't pass dev, suid and some other default options to related helper program, in this case `/sbin/mount.ntfs`; because they are considered default. These options should be effective and works if you are using the mount helper program directly:
`mount.ntfs -o exec,dev,suid /dev/disk/by-uuid/CE20D46C20D45D51 /mnt/data1`

The workaround I recommended is to modify NTFS-3G to remove the default nodev and nosuid.