# What is overriding the fstab permissions mounting option?

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab, options

**fstab:**

```
LABEL="Shared" /home/howard/Shared/ ntfs permissions,rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=howard,gid=howard,allow_other,noatime,fmask=033,dmask=022 0 2
```

Mount with:

```
mount LABEL="Shared"
```

mount reports:

> /dev/sda3 on /home/howard/Shared type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096)

Note "permissions" option was not honored, and instead "default_permissions" appears.  (Also `blksize=4096` is being added without my request.)  Why does the "permissions" option get changed to "default_permissions"?

I've tried both ntfs and ntfs-3g mount types.  They both return with a "fuseblk" mount type.

The permissions option allows each file's owner, group, and ugo_rwx permissions to be set independently.  With default_permissions you can only set these one time for all files in the filesystem, and you can't individual set each file's user, group and permissions.

*Debian 8.5, Cinnamon 2.2.16, Linux Kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64*

Comment: Answer: no, there is not a 2nd place which provides mounting information.  This is almost certainly an issue with ntfs-3g specifically.  Can you please clarify whether the first invocation of `mount` (using fstab) is performed with root privileges / sudo or not.  (This isn't as stupid as it sounds because it is specifically possible for ntfs-3g to be setuid-root).

Answer (score 1):

The permissions option is ignored and automatically changed to default_permissions whenever any of the following options is also included with it:

`uid`, `gid`, `umask`, `dmask`, or `fmask`

To help fix this you can use `user_id` and `group_id` in place of `uid` and `gid`.

But you must not use `umask`, `dmask` or `fmask` with `permissions`.

You'll know it's working when you get the following status from mount:

> Using default user mapping

---

Note that initially all files are owned by root.  You might want to change them recursively to be owned by you.